# NGiNX - Not returning sufficient headers for error(4xx, 5xx) Vs Success(2xx)

Tags: angular, nginx, server, cors, cors-anywhere

***Hello Friends,***

I have independently ask [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040293/angular-6-http-error-status-code-0-instead-of-401-400-any-except-200) in the same `context` but from `angular` perspective.

Kindly refer my `NGiNX` server [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040293/angular-6-http-error-status-code-0-instead-of-401-400-any-except-200) .

What I am phasing is, whenever my `Angular` app's `REST` request *successfully*(**200**) returns from server(*where `NGiNX` installed*) in such a case `NGiNX` returns `sufficient headers` along with `response` & I am able to successfully handle it **Vs** **Error** request/response.

Especial case is, I am unable to get `request status`. **For example**, if my API return `401, 400, 500..` **except 200** in such a case my `angular` `App` is getting `http response-status` as a "**Zero(0)**" irrespective of what server returns. My main assumption is due to **either** `CORS` issue(which is mainly all recommending to fix) or some hidden(for me).

**In Angular I am able to see below things(refer screen-shot),**
[image]

> My assumption is, if CORS issue then my 200 request response must also
>   not server. so my guess is CORS I have configured correctly.

*Any Help would be really appreciate in advanced!*

**NOTE -**

1. I am confuse whether it's `NGiNX` side an issue or `Angular` side. that's why I ask the same question under different tags(`Angular, Nginx`).
2. I have also implemented **SSL** at server side. so kindly consider this case as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add headers to 4xx and 5xx errors: When setting the headers, you must use the `always` param:

```
add_header <header_name> <value> always
```

See the docs at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header:

> Adds the specified field to a response header provided that the response code equals 200, 201 (1.3.10), 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, 307 (1.1.16, 1.0.13), or 308 (1.13.0)… If the `always` parameter is specified (1.7.5), the header field will be added regardless of the response code.